# Vim colorcolumn interrupted when using wrap

Tags: vim

When using `set colorcolumn=80` in conjunction with `set wrap`, the colored vertical column is interrupted, since wrapped lines are still considered as one single line. I think a solution might be to highlight columns 160, 240, ... as well, but I don't know enough Vimscript to implement this.

Please have a look at the following .gif animation to see what I mean:

[image: interrupted colorcolumn]

Is it possible to display the colorcolumn as a *continuous* vertical bar?

Comment: I like your demonstration of the problem.

Comment: It doesn't look _nice_, but at least it is _correct_ and unambiguous.

Comment: In my opinion, wrapping lines and `colorcolumn` are conceptually opposed: you wrap lines because you don't care about their actual length and you use `colorcolumn` when you care. I see no point in mixing the two.

Comment: You have a point there, @romainl. My main intent was to be able to leave `colorcolumn` always on, and switch between `wrap` and `nowrap` on demand (depending on content/file type). Defining a single short cut to quickly switch between `wrap/no colorcolumn` and `nowrap/colorcolumn` could be a workaround for my situation. I still think the original question as such is valid, so I'll leave it open.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't appear that vim provides a way of doing this by default.  However,
the `colorcolumn` option allows you to specify more than one column to highlight.  *(in a comma seperated list)*  So I think this should do what you want:

```
set colorcolumn=80,160,240
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid this does not work als expected, since the window/terminal width might be larger than 80 columns. When I `set columns=90` for example, I have to `set colorcolumn=80,166,252` (the first 4 columns are used for the line numbers). Is it possible to install some kind of listener and change `colorcolumn` automatically on resizing?

Comment: Yes, it probably is possible with the autocmd event `VimResized`.  I will look into it, and add to my answer if I find something

Comment: It seams to me that any way of trying to accomplish this would be unreliable and a bit hacky.  I will keep trying things, but ithere doesn't seem to be a very good way of doing it.